# How to convert binary string to an unsigned int?

Tags: c

I'm trying to convert a binary string to an unsigned int but I still can't get the way to make it possible, here is my code which probably won't make a lot of sense:

```
unsigned int binary_to_uint(const char *b)
{
    unsigned int k = 2;
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned int c;
    unsigned int len;
    if (b == NULL)
        return (0);
    len = strlen(b);
    for (c = len; c > 0; c--)
    {
        if (b[c] != 48 || b[c] != 49)
            return (0);
        if (b[c] == '1')
        {
            i += atoi(b) * k;
        }
        k *= 2;
    }
    return (i);
}
```

Comment: i have to detect if the number isn't 0 or 1 it'll return 0

Comment: i'm unsure of the concept of converting and how to make it

Comment: So you are trying to rather convert the digits of the string so "1234" as a string to be stored as the number 1234 or you want to convert the first 8 bytes of the string and map them to unsigned long long int number?

Comment: Please provide sample input and output. Is any length allowed?

Comment: You can use the character constants `'0'` and `'1'` instead of the ASCII decimal codes 48 and 49.

Comment: `i += atoi(b) * k;` during the loop, `b` will not change.

Comment: Your `for` loop checks `b[c]` locations for `c` values from `len` down to `1`. But `b[len]` will be a null terminator `'\0'` so `if (b[c] != 48 || b[c] != 49)` will fail on the first character tested.

Comment: You need to indent your code. Unindented code is hard to read and therefore hard to debug.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

condition in your if (b[c] != 48 || b[c] != 49) always true, and in C range of index is 0 to len-1

```
unsigned int binary_to_uint( const char *b)
{
 unsigned int k = 1;
 unsigned int i=0;
 int c;
 unsigned int len;

 len = strlen(b);

  for (c = len-1; c >= 0; c--)
 {
  if (b[c] != '0' && b[c] != '1')
      return (0);
    if (b[c] == '1')
    {
     i += k;
     }
    k *= 2;
}
 return (i);
}
```

Comment: @Gerhardh, edited answer according to your suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There are many problems in your code:

- If you start with index `len` you access the terminating `'\0'` byte of your string.
- You don't go down to 0 with your index meaning you miss the first digit.
- During the loop you always use `atoi(b)` which will not be very useful.
- You start from rightmost digit but use `k=2` for its value instead of 1.

Normally such a conversion is done following a simple scheme:

```
unsigned int binary_to_uint(const char *b)
{
  unsigned int val = 0;
  int i = 0;

  if (b == NULL)
    return 0;

  while (b[i] == '0' || b[i] == '1')
  {  // Found another digit.
    val <<= 1;
    val += b[i]-'0';
    i++;
  }
  return val;
}
```